# Unable to Unpickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, pickle

I am trying to unpickle an object sent via a socket

My server has this class

```
ActivePeerList = []

class PeerInfo():
  def __init__(self):
  self.hostname = ""
  self.cookie = None
  self.active = False
  self.TTL = 7200
  self.port = ""
  self.no_of_times = 0
  self.LastActiveDate = None
```

I append instances of this class into the list and send it via a socket to a client.

```
client[0].send(pickle.dumps(ActivePeerList))
```

I get this error when I try to unpickle i.e. *pickle.loads(client.recv(1024))*

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'PeerInfo' on <module '__main__' (<_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000000002A73828>)>
```

Is transferring unkown classes(i.e.unknown to the client) forbidden?? Even if it is, I am engulfing it in a List object. So it should work. RIght??

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The class definition isn't transferred by pickle so it must be present when unpickling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pickling handles functions and classes by (with some boilerplate) transferring their qualified name, to be looked up on unpickling. It makes the resulting pickle much smaller, but because it doesn't transfer anything *about* them, what you're trying won't work. You *must* have the referenced class on the unpickling side under the same qualified name, or it won't work.

If you want to work with serialized data of an arbitrary form (for which the client lacks a full definition), I'd recommend looking at JSON or XML (both of which avoid the security risks of unpickling pickles from potentially untrusted sources).

Comment: Alternatively, if the client has access to the class definition, simply importing the class from wherever should be sufficient.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: `pickle` will do this automatically; it uses the qualified name to attempt an import of the necessary module to gain access to the class/function (even if it hasn't been imported yet). Only reason you'd need to take direct action to enable it is if you installed the module to a weird place and need to manually modify `sys.path` or the `sys.modules` cache to make the class/function findable (and at that point, you're in ugly kludge territory and you've no one to blame but yourself).